# Angular 8 prod build takes over 50 mins

Tags: angular, angular8

I have recently upgraded my application to Angular 8 and the following is the prod build command:

node --max_old_space_size=16384 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot=true --output-hashing=none

Before when the application was on Angular 7 the prod build took less than 15 mins. But after upgrading to Angular 8.3.10 the prod build takes over 50 mins. Can you please let me know how I can improve the prod build time.

Comment: How much Ram is on the build machine?

Comment: dude what are the specs of the machine, does it use an old HDD?

Comment: @MotassemMK It is a Windows server 2012 machine with 18gb RAM.